Сохранение данных в словарь Python, telebot
Код для примера:
BACK_IDS = {}
# Декоратор для добавления id в словарь для отслеживания колбеков для кнопки "назад"
def lib_id_del_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(call, bot):
        if call.from_user.id not in BACK_IDS:
            BACK_IDS[call.from_user.id] = []
            BACK_IDS[call.from_user.id].append(call.data)
        else:
            BACK_IDS[call.from_user.id].append(call.data)
        # Вызываем функцию, переданную как аргумент
        func(call, bot)
        print(BACK_IDS)
    return wrapper

Всё прекрасно работает, id и колбеки добавляются в словарь, но словарь при перезапуске бота обнуляется. Как решить проблему? Как-то с инициализацией словаря поиграть?

Записывать информацию   в  базу данных, словарь существует только в оперативной памяти
